# Creating a pipeline and CMake file to compile a repo in Gitlab

Tags: c++, cmake, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have a repo in gitlab that consist of about 10 files that have several c++ files that I want to execute/run/compile. I am trying to use the gitlab ci/cd pipeline using gcc to run all the programs in the files and I need a make file as well. I created a pipeline that looks like this:

```
image: gcc

before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install make

build-job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - cd sw_repo
        - mkdir build
        - cd build
        - cmake ..
        - make
        # basically I just want to compile my c++ code that's in my repo
```

This is all I have so far for my pipeline and for my makefile I have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.21.2")

project(VS_Code)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# I want to execute my repo called VS_SW that holds the files to my c++ code
# I have multiple c++ files I want to execute so I don't know what to put here
# because I want it to be more than one 
add_executable(VS_Code repo_file.cpp)
```

I don't know how to get the CMake file and the gitlab pipeline to work together, like I said I'm just trying to get all the code to compile that's in the folders in the repo.

Comment: for example https://gitlab.com/CLIUtils/modern-cmake/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L1 https://github.com/StableCoder/cmake-scripts/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml#L42 https://medium.com/@yann.cardaillac/simple-cmake-integration-with-gitlab-pipelines-603fe0574deb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312630/how-to-integrate-cmake-in-gitlab-repository-for-continuous-integrationci etc.